# Advanced positioning inside a scrollview in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I am currently working with a scrollview and using grid and stacklayout to position things. It is working fine when I do pretty basic layouts, for example my view first cointans an image and after that a lot of text, but if you keep scrolling a bit I am looking to create a pretty advanced layout further down and the goal is for it to look like this:

[image]

I am not quite sure how to tackle this and accomplish such a layout inside a scrollview without using for instance absolutelayout (that i have tried working with inside the scrollview but it keeps giving me trouble, things not appearing etc).

This is my base code with the image and the text:

```
<ScrollView>
 <Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Image Aspect = "AspectFit" Grid.Row="0" x:Name = "image" />

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding = "10,10,10,0" >

        <Label XAlign = "Center" x:Name = "name" FontSize = "15" FontAttributes = "Bold" TextColor = "Black" FontFamily = "Helvetica Neue" />

        <Label XAlign = "Center" x:Name = "date" FontSize = "13" TextColor = "Black" FontFamily = "Helvetica Neue"  />

        <StackLayout Padding = "20,20,20,0" >

        <Label x:Name = "text" FontSize = "12" TextColor = "Black" FontFamily = "Helvetica Neue" />
        </StackLayout> 
        </StackLayout>

  </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

How do I need to continue my code in order to add a similar layout to the image i posted above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a StackLayout as first child of ScrollView, and inside that add another Grid below the first one. Or inside your StackLayout that is in Grid.Row=1

```
<ScrollView>
  <StackLayout>
      <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Image Aspect = "AspectFit" Grid.Row="0" x:Name = "image" />

          <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding = "10,10,10,0" >

              <Label XAlign = "Center" x:Name = "name" FontSize = "15" FontAttributes = "Bold" TextColor = "Black" FontFamily = "Helvetica Neue" />

              <Label XAlign = "Center" x:Name = "date" FontSize = "13" TextColor = "Black" FontFamily = "Helvetica Neue"  />

              <StackLayout Padding = "20,20,20,0" >

                  <Label x:Name = "text" FontSize = "12" TextColor = "Black" FontFamily = "Helvetica Neue" />
              </StackLayout> 
          </StackLayout>
       </Grid>
       <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            Your content here

       </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: the only problem is that the image ` <Image Aspect = "AspectFit" Grid.Row="0" x:Name = "image" />` does not reach the edge of the screen because of that first stacklayout under scrollview. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try adding HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" on all parent layouts

Comment: Added it on the scrollview, stacklayout, grid and also the image itself but the image does not position itself to the edges. When I try other pictures someitmes the image gets even smaller so it is like a small cube in the center. Do I need to change the first ` <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>`to auto?

Comment: Sorry, did not see the "AspectFit" before now, try AspectFill or just Fill on the image. AspectFit is your best bet since it keeps the aspect/ratio of the image soruce